# Is there an SEO penalty for writing URLs with segments that have no index content?

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

I am working on a bootstrap based responsive website. The dropdown menus in the main website navigation are opened with a click rather than a hover. There is no index content for each section, only specific page links in the dropdown.

Is there any SEO penalty for having content located at:

www.mysite.com/books/moby-dick

when

www.mysite.com/books

results in a 404 error?

I could generate index pages with links to all children if I had to, but I'd rather avoid creating any content that isn't meant to be viewed directly.

I would like to organize the pages by "folder" using mod_rewrite which I have a pretty good handle on at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it, Search Engines place no relevance on one page's URL in relation to another page's URL.  Are you looking for some documentation. What search engine are you looking for documentation on? I'm not even sure if that type of info is "documented" but if you think about it, the order of words in a URL only have meaning to us as humans. An engine doesn't place importance of links further up or down the url hierarchy. It wouldn't make sense.

I don't even think your page moby-dick would have a positive/negative impact on the domains home page. Google at least treats every URL as a unique page, hence the "Page Rank" algorithm.  Not the site hierarchy algorithm.

Comment: I think as far as pretty links go, it seems like a good idea to leave the indexes blank. In fact, doing anything to try to "fool" google, for example always feels rightly like it could be trouble. I just don't know if there's a penalty for creating structures that aren't fully traversable. I'll be back later .. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: As a power user, I don't like that.  If there is a directory structure, it is nice to be able to browse it.  But this answer is correct, search engines won't care one way or the other.

Comment: I agree. The hierarchy of a URL, in my own opinion should work at each level. But many times that is not the case, especially in the case of an application where you have a `domain.com/controller/action/key` type URL. Typically this wouldn't always work at each level. Regardless the question is answered, to a search engine, not a single ---- is given.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I really appreciate it. I was a bit conflicted about using clicks to open nav menus rather than hover, but the concensus seems to be that when a good portion of your users have touch screens, the click is better.